# How can I make sure an ellipsis appears if the overflow comes where a natural word break is?

Tags: css, ellipsis

The cells in this table ALL have too much content, so all should end with an ellipsis. But I found that the ellipsis does not appear if a natural word break happens where the ellipsis should be. These two cells have the same styling:

[image]

I can't figure out how to get the ellipsis to appear at the end of the text in the first cell. Here is my code:

```
td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.inner {
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 56px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

<td>
  <div class="inner">An award winning podcast and nationally syndicated radio show that looks at the innovations that are changing our lives.</div>
<td>
<td>
  <div class="inner">https://killerinnovations.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/cropped-KIlogofavicon-32x32.jpg</div>
<td>
```

The purpose for the .inner div is because td does not respect max-height, and I want these to be no more than 3 lines high. How do I get back my missing ellipsis?

Also, it's undesirable that the second cell puts an ellipsis at the end of each line, instead of wrapping the whole thing and putting just one ellipsis at the end. But I can live with that.

Answer (score 1):

If, however, you do not like `white-space: nowrap;`, then there is no way to create the 3-dots effect with pure css.

However, I'd suggest doing something like this, as seen in Reddit, where you fade away the content slowly.
You can change the direction of the fading by changing the `90deg` value in the CSS.

```css
div {
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #000 60%, transparent);
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 11px;
  width: 250px;
  height: calc(1em);
  resize: horizontal;
}
```

```html
<div>Try to resize me by dragging the lower right corner. Very very long text may go here so that it overflows!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `ellipsis` you need to specify 2 other rules as well. They are `white-space: nowrap;` and `overflow: hidden`.

Try to run the snippet and resize the gray box.

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  
  resize: horizontal;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div>Very very long text may go here so that it overflows.</div>
```

Comment: I had tried the nowrap but found this restricts it to a single line, and I want to display up to 3 lines to give a better preview of the contents. (I am already using overflow: hidden)

Comment: There is no way to do this in pure CSS. What I would advise is to copy what Google does with their chrome tabs - they don't use 3 dots, but instead slowly fade the text away until it can no longer be seen. This alternative is possible with pure CSS.

Comment: Bear with me, ill post another answer to show how to do this.